# CircleCi Artifacts expiry

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci, artifacts, continuous-delivery

What is the expiry of CircleCi artifacts? For example, if a build has created with some artifacts (android apk file for example) then till when can I download those artifacts?

I have googled it a lot but didn't found any answer so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I asked the same question with CircleCi support. Here is what they said:

> At this time we do not expire artifacts, but we do request that you not expect them to be good for long-term storage in the event they need to be deleted for some reason.
>
> When we finalize our expiry policy we will document it.

---

I also asked about the maximum size of artifacts, here is their response:

> Similar answer. No limit, but we ask that you only include what is needed as it will result in longer build times due to uploading, and can sometimes cause issues retrieving if the sizes or counts are very high.

I found an issue in GitHib ([CircleCi-docs-issue#122](https://github.com/circleci/circleci-docs/issues/122)), explaining that it's maximum size is 3 GB.
So they said that,

> That may be an S3 limit. I would consider that excessive and ask if you have a file near that size that you gzip it for make things smoother for everybody.

**TL;DR -** There's no such expiry of CircleCi artifacts and with no size limit.